# State issue in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I have below JSX in Child Component.

```
<td>
  <div>
    {this.props.image_element} 
  </div> 
</td>
```

I have `function` in Parent Component is like below

```
image_element= (image_name) => {        
        if(image_name) {
            this.update_photostatus('image');
        }
        else {
            console.log('hello');
            this.update_photostatus('input');
        }
   }
```

and

```
update_photostatus = value => {
        this.setState({photostatus: value});
    }
```

I am getting output in `console` is like below

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing with us your components?

Comment: As the error says you are updating the state in the wrong lifecycle phase, meaning that the `setState()` trigger the `render()` and you already rendering the component, so it cause the 2nd error.

Comment: If I understand your code you invoke method image_element inside method render() and method image_element invoke setState(). In documentation is written: "Thanks to the setState() call, React knows the state has changed, and calls the render() method again to learn what should be on the screen." https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html and it cause infinite loop.

Comment: Please do not post only fragments of a component. It's hard to understand it like that. The problem seems to be that you are rendering `this.props.image_element` in your child which probably is a function passed from the parent and will be treated as a stateless functional component. So if that function gets called during rendering it will lead to a `setState()` being called which is not allowed during rendering. It will lead to an endless updating cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call setState within componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate or render method, unless you have conditionals that restrict that change (even then be careful). When you setState inside one of these, you are likely to get the Maximum update depth exceeded message back.